# Using Unicode Tags to represent something other than a subdivision flag?

Tags: unicode, emoji

To this day, [unicode tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tags_(Unicode_block)) are [exclusively used to represent subdivision flags](https://emojipedia.org/search/?q=E007F). But are they limited to subdivisions? Can I use them for instance to represent a language flag like [the Esperanto Flag](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Esperanto_flag) using the mapping:
 [+ `[e]` + `[o]` + `[cancel]`](https://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect?s=%F0%9F%8F%B4%F3%A0%81%A5%F3%A0%81%AF%F3%A0%81%BF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You *can* use any sequence of Unicode characters to represent anything. The trouble is that nobody will be able to understand your message unless you’re following an established protocol.

If you want to conform to the Unicode Standard, or more specifically [Unicode Technical Standard #51 (Unicode Emoji)](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/), then the tag sequence you are considering is invalid, has no meaning, and should ideally be displayed using a special “error” glyph to indicate its malformedness. [Annex C](https://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/tr51-18.html#valid-emoji-tag-sequences) of UTS #51 has more information on that matter.

As of the time of writing, there is only one type of valid emoji tag sequences: Those representing flags of regions with a region code ultimately derived from [ISO 3166-2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2). The Esperanto language does not possess such a region code (because it is not a region) and thus cannot be represented with this mechanism. I recommend employing [private-use characters](https://www.unicode.org/faq/private_use.html).